# Different SSL states as seen by Safari, Chrome and Firefox

Tags: tls, web-browser, certificate-authority, chrome, firefox

Today, I visited some sites of the German DHL group.

While **Chrome and Safari complain** about an invalid certificate of

[image]

**Firefox accepts** it.

- Which one is right, which one is wrong?
- Which decision should a user trust?

This is what Safari reports:

[image]

To make this situation a bit more complicated, **Firefox and Chrome accept** the following link, but **Safari complains about an invalid SSL certificate**:

- [Link to Paket.de password recorvery](https://www.paket.de/pkp/appmanager/pkp/desktop?_nfpb=true&_pageLabel=pkp_portal_page_login&portletInstance_customerLogin_actionOverride=/de/deutschepost/ubbrief/dhl/pkp/portlets/externallogin/resetPassword&portletInstance_customerLogin%7BactionForm.username%7D=)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I was unable to replicate any issues with these sites' SSL certificates in any browser.  Could this problem by unique to your machine?  Stale DNS?  Old CA root stores?  Malware?

Comment: It would help if you provided english translation of the error description.

Comment: Chrome and IE use the MS list of CAs, Firefox the Mozilla list. Those lists might differ, and can also be changed by by the user/installed applications.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp It's complaining that the CA is invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The screenshots show that the problem is not in the end-entity certificate (the actual server's certificate) but in the intermediate CA which issued it (the one just above): that CA is also shown with the "red cross". The error messages you see just tell you that the server's certificate cannot be used because its issuing CA is not trusted. To know *why* that issuing CA is not trusted, you have to click on it.

From my own systems, I see no problem with that issuing CA, and my browsers are happy with it (Firefox, Chromium on Linux; IE 8 on Windows XP). A *possible* reason may be a failure to obtain the CRL and/or OCSP information from the "DPWN Root", making it impossible for Safari to ascertain whether the "DPWN SSL CA" certificate was revoked or not (use of CRL and/or OCSP depends on the browser, the OS, and the configuration of both, so this may explain conflicting results).